# Find mean from subset of one column based on ranking in the top 50 of another column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has the following columns:

```
> str(wbr)
'data.frame':   214 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ countrycode      : Factor w/ 214 levels "ABW","ADO","AFG",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
     $ countryname      : Factor w/ 214 levels "Afghanistan",..: 10 5 1 6 2 202 8 9 4 7 ...
 $ gdp_per_capita   : num  19913 35628 415 2738 4091 ...
     $ literacy_female  : num  96.7 NA 17.6 59.1 95.7 ...
 $ literacy_male    : num  96.9 NA 45.4 82.5 98 ...
     $ literacy_all     : num  96.8 NA 31.7 70.6 96.8 ...
 $ infant_mortality : num  NA 2.2 70.2 101.6 13.3 ...
     $ illiteracy_female: num  3.28 NA 82.39 40.85 4.31 ...
 $ illiteracy_mele  : num  3.06 NA 54.58 17.53 1.99 ...
     $ illiteracy_male  : num  3.06 NA 54.58 17.53 1.99 ...
 $ illiteracy_all   : num  3.18 NA 68.26 29.42 3.15 ...
```

I would like to find the mean of `illiteracy_all` from the top 50 countries with the highest GDP.

Before you answer me I need to inform you that the data frame has `NA` values meaning that if I want to find the mean I would have to write:

```
mean(wbr$illiteracy_all, na.rm=TRUE)
```

For a reproducible example, let's take:

```
data.df <- data.frame(x=101:120, y=rep(c(1,2,3,NA), times=5))
```

So how could I average the `y` values for e.g. the top 5 values of `x`?

```
> data.df
     x  y
1  101  1
2  102  2
3  103  3
4  104 NA
5  105  1
6  106  2
7  107  3
8  108 NA
9  109  1
10 110  2
11 111  3
12 112 NA
13 113  1
14 114  2
15 115  3
16 116 NA
17 117  1
18 118  2
19 119  3
20 120 NA
```

Comment: use this code : `mean(wbr$illiteracy_all[wbr$GDP>=sort(wbr$GDP)[length(wbr$GDP)-50]], na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Hi guys. First of all thanks for the assistance, really appreciate it. For starters i used the code above but i got the wrong results. Then i used the following pieces of code `rank2<-order(wbr$gdp_per_capita, decreasing = TRUE )` and rank3 <- rank2[1:50] and summary(wbr) which provided me the code. My question now is: could i do this in one line of code? as i said before, i used the code given above but it didnt produce the correct results. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the following would work:

```
mean(data.df[rank(-data.df$x)<=5,"y"], na.rm=TRUE)

mean(data.df$y[rank(-data.df$x)<=5], na.rm=TRUE)

with(data.df, mean(y[rank(-x)<=5], na.rm=TRUE))
```

---

To unpack why this works, note first that `rank` gives ranks in a different order to what you might expect, `1` being the rank of the *smallest* number not the largest:

```
> rank(data.df$x)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

We can get round that [by negating the input](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3321/rank-in-r-descending-order):

```
> rank(-data.df$x)
 [1] 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

So now ranks `1` to `5` are the "top 5". If we want a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` to indicate the position of the top 5 we can use:

```
> rank(-data.df$x)<=5
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[14] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

(In reality you might find you have some ties in your data set. This is only going to cause issues if the 50th position is tied. You might want to have a look at the `ties.method` argument for `rank` to see how you want to handle this.)

So let's grab the values of `y` in those positions:

```
> data.df[rank(-data.df$x)<=5,"y"]
[1] NA  1  2  3 NA
```

Or you could use:

```
> data.df$y[rank(-data.df$x)<=5]
[1] NA  1  2  3 NA
```

So now we know what to input into `mean`:

```
> mean(data.df[rank(-data.df$x)<=5,"y"], na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 2
```

Or:

```
> mean(data.df$y[rank(-data.df$x)<=5], na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 2
```

Or if you don't like repeating the name of the data frame, use `with`:

```
> with(data.df, mean(y[rank(-x)<=5], na.rm=TRUE))
[1] 2
```

Comment: Hi guys. First of all thanks for the assistance, really appreciate it.

Comment: i also used the following but couldnt get it to work `mean(wbr[rank(-wbr$gdp_per_capita)<=50,"wbr$illiteracy_all"], na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Look carefully at the code above. You have tried to select a column called `"wbr$illiteracy_all"` but it should be just `"illiteracy_all"`. Compare: I have written `"y"` in that position, not `"data.df$y"`.